# Refactoring methods in Javascript (adding / deleting items from an array)

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I encountered a question where I have to refactor the code below that has several errors in it:

```
function thingsToBuy() {
  var list = [
    "milk",
    "bread",
    "bananas"
  ];
  return {
    removeItem: function(name) {
      list.filter(item => item === name);
    },
    addItem: function() {
      return list.push();
    },
    getList: function(list) {
      return list;
    }
  };
}
```

So far, I have this:

```
function thingsToBuy() {
  let list = [
    "milk",
    "bread",
    "bananas"
  ];
  return {
    removeItem: function(name) {
      for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(list[i] === name) 
        return list.splice(i, 1)
      }
    },
    addItem: function(item) {
      list.push(item);
  
    },
    getList: function() {
      return list;
    }
  };
}
```

Am I missing anything or have I implemented anything wrong? Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
function thingsToBuy() {
  var list = [
    "milk",
    "bread",
    "bananas"
  ];
  return {
    removeItem: function(name) {
      list = list.filter(item => item !== name);
      return list;
    },
    addItem: function(item) {
      list.push(item);
      return list;
    },
    getList: function() {
      return list;
    }
  };
}
```

This is a basic exercise to see if you understand how JS works.
The function gives you some methods to mutate the list variable. You should read more about Array.filter, Array.push to see their input and output.